# Setting alt/option key to Meta in Emacs on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, meta, iterm

Yes, I've googled around and none of the answers provided seem to work. I recently got a new computer and moved my `.emacs` over and some things aren't working. Specifically the alt/option key is not detected as meta in emacs.

I'm on:

```
Darwin punk.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Mon Jan  9 23:07:29 PST 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.2.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(if (system-is-mac)
  (setq ns-command-modifier 'meta))
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
```

And I'm running `iterm2 build 3.0.13`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this link help any -- **"Making iTerm to translate 'meta-key' in the same way as in other OSes"**?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196357/making-iterm-to-translate-meta-key-in-the-same-way-as-in-other-oses

Comment: That sort of worked. It at least set me on the right direction. I'll submit the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This can be fixed from iterm2. Thanks for [lawlist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112489/lawlist) for pointing me in the right direction.

Select `Iterm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles` Brings up the profiles view.

On that pane select `Keys` then `Left option key acts as` and select `+Esc`.