# How to disable the ESC as a meta key in iterm2?

Tags: bash, macos, iterm2, byobu

I'm using vim mode on bash terminal and when I press ESC terminal should change from INSERT mode to NORMAL. The problem is that ESC is a meta key and terminal waits half a second to change the mode. Is there a way to disable the meta key or reduce timeout in bash prompt?

This is not a duplicate of [Making iTerm to translate 'meta-key' in the same way as in other OSes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196357/making-iterm-to-translate-meta-key-in-the-same-way-as-in-other-oses) as I am not interested in remapping Option to act as ESC, I want to disable the ESC to work as a meta.

Comment: You mention byobu; it's not iTerm2 that's waiting for additional input, but `tmux` (or whatever terminal multiplexer byobu is using).

Comment: After disabling byobu the problem still persists. I think bash is waiting for the ESC-b or ESC-f sequence to move one word back or forward.

Answer (score 3):

When you press `Esc`, `bash` waits for 500 milliseconds to see if you want *just* an escape key, or if you want another Readline command that starts with an `Esc`. You can decrease the timeout from `.inputrc` with

```
set keyseq-timeout 250
```

Comment: YES!!! it's keyseq, not keyset and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Gah, stupid autocorrect. I'm pretty sure I typed `keyseq` initially :)