# emacs control D key binding overridden

Tags: macos, cocoa, google-apps-script

### Any solutions out there for dealing with google script code-editor turning "forward delete" into a "kill line" binding? I'm used to the hidden cocoa/emacs derived navigation keys. Google decided to mess with **control-d**.

Clarifications:

1. This occurs when using the code editor. (edit-view?)
2. I would rather stop the google behavior than cope with it.

To understand more how fluid the [control-key navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162896/emacs-on-mac-os-x-leopard-key-bindings) can be 
(and therefore how annoying when missing), try this...

1. set caps-lock to be the control key
2. open a cocoa browser like Safari and
3. start a script at https://script.google.com/
4. switch briefly to address bar

   1. hit ctrl+a (goes to start of line)
   2. hit ctrl+d (characters get deleted 1 at a time)
   3. hit escape
5. switch to script area and try same thing (whole lines get munched!)

Comment: Are you talking about in a web view, or…?

Comment: When editing the script in a web browser, so an edit view I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I noticed that this problem no longer exists. So when editing a script file in the macro editor, emacs shortcuts WORK as expected. I cannot tell if they simply removed a bug or override, or actually patched it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean while you're working on your program in that editor, press the forward-delete key. On Apple's laptops and wireless keyboard, it's fn-delete (where by “delete”, I mean the backward delete, the key that is a.k.a. “backspace”).

Comment: I may have to accept that. I just much prefer to keep my fingers on the home-keys. That's what makes the emacs shortcuts (available in 95% of OSX apps) so nice.

Comment: They're available wherever the text editing is being run by Cocoa (because Cocoa implements them). In a web-based editor, the web page is what's running it. You could try writing a Safari extension to patch Google's script, but I would expect it to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).