# How to remap the Caps Lock key to Control in OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, emacs

I want to use Emacs and need remap the Caps key to Ctrl (switch them). How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162896/emacs-on-mac-os-x-leopard-key-bindings?rq=1

Comment: The first answer still works in Catalina! Also this is very precise and useful and not a duplicate of the one it's marked as duplicate of. I wanted exactly this and found it! Recommend changing the title to "... in macOS" (don't mention 10.8) and removing duplicate status.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Just go to **Apple Menu -> System Preferences... -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Tab -> Modifier Keys** and select `Control` for `Caps Lock`.

Comment: If you are using an external keyboard, you'll want to select it from the dropdown at the top of the **Modifier Keys** window.

Comment: Does anyone know how this can be done from a script i can run from the terminal?  I like to have to all such configurations automated so it's easy to switch computers and profiles.

Comment: @zumalifeguard http://superuser.com/questions/545208/remap-keys-via-command-line-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Is there any way to add other keys to the select list, such as Backspace, without using third party software?

Comment: Would be nice to have capslock be control in terminal, etc, and command otherwise.