# Mac OSX: Latest Emacs's key bindings not working

Tags: macos, emacs

Basically, I installed the latest Emacs 24.3 on my MAC OSX. I am completely new to Emacs.

Is there an equivalent of `.vimrc` in emacs? What is it called because I want to change the key bindings?

**Problem 1:** Instead of having `Ctrl` as `C-` key, I want to have `CMD` as `C-`. What is the code for this?

**Problem 2:** I notice that traditionally we have `C- right arrow` key as Slurp and `C-left arrow` key as barf. But on my mac, they don't work anymore and they are replaced by `C-M-j` and `C-M-e`. It took me a while to find out about this. I want to know why is it that a lot of the key bindings are so much different from Emacs on Windows? If I want the key bindings to be consistent with the ones on the Windows computer, is there a convenient way to do this or do I have to remap every single key manually?

Comment: Actually I think this question is a closer reference: http://superuser.com/questions/160150/changing-emacs-bindings-on-mac-os-x-for-command-to-be-meta especially explore the `M-x customize-group RET ns RET` settings in emacs.

Comment: Which Emacs is this?  They behave rather differently on OSX depending on which variant you install.  Try http://aquamacs.org/ if it's not what you currently have.

Comment: Also, over here in the civilized world, Windows is hardly any yardstick for "working properly".

Answer (score 2):

The `emacs` equivalent of the `.vimrc` is the so called [**init file**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile) which can either be `~/.emacs`, `~/_emacs`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

You can change keybindings using the `define-key`, `local-set-key`, and `global-set-key` commands, check the blog post [Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/) for a more complete introduction.

Basically, if you want to change the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to open a file, you have to add

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'find-file)
```

to your config.

You might want to check the SO question ["Emacs on Mac OS X Leopard key bindings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162896/emacs-on-mac-os-x-leopard-key-bindings) for help on **Problem 1** (using <kbd>Command</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

I'm not completely sure what your second problem is, but as far as I know, there is no way to tell `emacs` to gather system global keybindings and use them internally. Hence, if you OS has some set of keybindings which you'd like to mirror in `emacs`, you need to remap them manually.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem 2**: I notice that traditionally we have C- right arrow key as **Slurp** and C-left arrow key as **barf**. But on my mac, they
>   don't work anymore

With [emacsformacosx](https://emacsformacosx.com) on OSX 10.10.5, I can  `slurp` and `barf` with these  key sequences:

```
C-)   (slurp)  
C-}   (barf)  

M-(   (wrap)
```

Here's an example from "[Clojure for the Brave and True](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/)":

Suppose you have this:

```
(+ 1 2 3 4)
```

and you want to get this:

```
(+ 1 (* 2 3) 4)
```

First, place the cursor("the point") here:

```
(+ 1 |2 3 4)
```

(The `2` will be highlighted.)

Then hit `M-(` (that's <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>) to wrap the `2` in parentheses:

```
(+ 1 (|2) 3 4)
```

Then type the `*` and a space:

```
(+ 1 (* |2) 3 4)
```

To `slurp` the 3, hit `C-)`  (that's <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>):

```
(+ 1 (* |2 3) 4)
```

To `barf` the 3, place the cursor anywhere inside the inner parentheses and hit `C-}` (that's <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> ):

```
(+ 1 (* 2) 3 4)
```