# Mapping the caps lock key win vim

Tags: macvim, vim

I am trying to map the caps lock key to do an action in MacVIM, but I cannot figure out how to map that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (unless  there are big changes in mac version): vim uses outdated byte queue instead of keypress queue and CapsLock is not represented by any byte sequence.

// It is still possible to configure your system so that CapsLock will produce something that can be captured by vim.

Answer (score 1):

This SO question: [Using Caps Lock as Esc in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-on-a-mac) has some suggestions, which they characterize as a choice between "a complicated, half-baked solution or installing a third-party piece of hackery."