# Notifying when using high CPU. Via AppleScript or Automator?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, cpu-usage, automator

I'd like to automate that whenever a process is using more than 50% CPU 
it sends a notification to my Notification Center

I'm using [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) for sending trough notifications
but I'm a bit stuck on what the best method is for creating this automation.

Should I use Automator.app or create a custom AppleScript and if so,
how do I make it to always be on?

Comment: See also on AskDifferent, [Is there an app that will notify me (in notifications center) if a process is using up a high percentage of CPU for a specified amount of time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/90270/19289)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is for interactive use, let me suggest a **pragmatic alternative**:

- Run **Activity Monitor**.
- Control-click its dock icon.
- Select `Dock Icon > Show CPU Usage` - or, for a floating window, `Monitors > Show CPU Usage`.

You'll get a per-core display of current CPU usage - clicking on it will show the full  Activity Monitor window, where you can sort by CPU usage.

---

If you do need an **automated solution**, I suggest:

- writing a **`bash` script** that uses `top` to find the highest-CPU-percentage task and invokes `terminal-notifier`, if above the threshold.
- scheduling that script as a **`launchd` task for periodic invocation**.

Automator and AppleScript are probably too heavy for such - presumably frequent - background activity.

Even running `top` itself uses quite a bit of CPU.

---

Here's a simple bash script that roughly does what you want:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read pct name < <(top -l 2 -n 1 -F -o cpu -stats cpu,command | tail -1)
if (( ${pct%.*} >= 50 )); then
  /Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier \
    -message "Process > 50%: $name ($pct%)"
fi
```

Note that this takes *at least* 2 seconds to run, because 2 samples (1 second apart) must be collected to calculate CPU-usage percentages, so consider that when determining how frequently to invoke the command.

**Update** - see below for step-by-step implementation instructions.

References:

- As for scheduling the script to have `launchd` run it on login: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872222/45375
- The general format of `launchd` `*.plist` files is described at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html or `man launchd.plist`; `StartInterval` is the key for specifying invocations every N seconds.

---

**Step-by-step instructions for implementing the automated solution:**

- **Create the bash script**:

  - Create plain-text file `~/watchcpu` (i.e., file `watchcpu` in your home folder), paste the above bash script into it, and save it.
- **Create the per-user launch agent for invocation at login and periodic invocation thereafter**:

  - Create plain-text file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/WatchCPU.plist`, paste the following XML document into it, and save it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>WatchCPU</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>. ~/watchcpu</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- **Load the per-user launch agent** to activate it:

  - Run the following command in Terminal (only needed *once*; from then on, the file will auto-load on every login):

```sh
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/WatchCPU.plist
```

Note:

- You're free to choose your own filenames and a different location for your bash script, but the launch agent `.plist` file MUST reside in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` in order to be loaded automatically at login.
- The interval (key `StartInterval`) is chosen at 15 seconds; again, you're free to change that, but note that choosing more frequent invocations doesn't make much sense, because `launchd` (the service that invokes launch agents) *throttles* agents whose execution time is too close to the invocation interval; I'm unclear on the details, but in the solution at hand an interval of 10 seconds results in frequent throttling notices in `system.log` (check via Console.app).

Comment: This worked better than the above option for me. Created a new Automator app and made it run shell script, and added it to login items. 
Thanks

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh: Glad to hear it. How did you achieve the _periodic_ invocation? Did you just put a loop into the `bash` script?

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh: Because I was curious, I've implemented the bash script / launchd (per-user launch agent) solution - see my update with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: thanks! The Automator flow I created still got some issues, will see what yours does.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pull the CPU usage to use either with a script or in an Automator workflow. Here's a script that you can schedule to run on a schedule and will notify if usage is over 50%:

```
set theDelay to 3 -- number of seconds to sample the CPU
set CPUusage to do shell script "top -F -l " & theDelay & " -n 1 -stats cpu | grep 'CPU usage:' | tail -1 | cut -d. -f1"
set idlePercent to word -2 of CPUusage as number
if idlePercent < 50 then display notification ("CPU usage is at " & (100 - idlePercent) & "%.") with title "CPU Usage"
```

See the comments to follow the editing of the do shell script command to allow for getting the integer naturally from the shell command to work better with non-English systems.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't seem to work, I stress tested my cpu by running `yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null &` and got the following error: _error "\"44.22\" can't be converted to type number." number -1700 from "44.22" to number_

Comment: Are you non-English system. You can add an explicit number coercion and that might fix it. I added it above. You might need a different method to pull the idle % number but that would be a piece of cake to figure out. By the way, to test, just change the < to a >. You don't have to load the system. Capture the CPUusage string and post here if you need help parsing the number.

Comment: You're solving a _different_ problem in determining the _overall_ CPU-use percentage, whereas @Thibmaekelbergh - the way I read the question - is looking for when a _single_ process uses more than 50% of the CPU.

Comment: While invoking `grep` as `GREP` will work on the case-sensitive OSX filesystem, I suggest using the case as in the actual executable filename, `grep` (just to form a more portable habit).

Comment: Good points, mklement. I changed the grep. I see now the distinction regarding single vs overall CPU. Would just need to adjust the line used from top, similar to what you did. If he's happy with a bash script, I'm happy.

Comment: Just to clarify `number of seconds to sample the CPU`: strictly speaking you're specifying the _number of sampling runs_, spaced by the interval at which to take samples (defaults to 1 second, can be changed with `-s <numIntegralSecs>`). Curiously, though, `top` waits for an _additional_ interval _after_ outputting the last sample - no idea why.

Comment: Right again. My guess was that it: samples - waits - samples - waits - returns.  That's why I just short handed to "number of seconds". I set that up with a property in case he wanted to save the AS as a keep running applescript app, and then could use the theDelay as the delay interval.

Comment: I see (any idea why it waits again at the end?). Note that since the sampling itself takes time and the overall execution time is delay + delay * processing-time-per-sample, the interval on the AppleScript side should be _greater_ to avoid overlapping invocations.

Comment: Re potential locale issues: `top` behaves the same in all locales (is not locale-aware; but even if it didn't, `do shell script` without explicitly setting the locale actually defaults to the generic "C" locale). Thus, your command always returns a number with `.` as the decimal separator, irrespective of locale. AppleScript itself, by contrast, does respect the system locale, and in the case at hand - Belgian locale, if I were to guess - breaks when trying to convert the `.`-based string to a number. A simple fix is to have the shell command return an _integer_ by adding `| cut -d. -f1'

Comment: I'll be curious to see if s/he posts the CPUusage string from his/her locale. The explicit coercion in AS should also fix. I suspect we're done hearing from them tho.

Comment: No, it is precisely the explicit number conversion on the AppleScript side that breaks in locales that use something _other_ than `.` as the decimal separator: AppleScript, being generally locale-aware (with the curious exception of `do shell script`), expects a _locale-appropriate_ number string, while your shell command always returns a number with "." as the decimal separator. And, as I said, invoking `do shell script` does NOT respect the system locale - unless you include an explicit `export LANG=...` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification... I completely understand now. I didn't understand what you were saying in the earlier explanation, but now I get it. I'll update the answer for any future reader.

Comment: I appreciate the update; perhaps you could also add a brief explanation (or at least explicitly point to the comments), as not everyone will necessarily read through this lengthy exchange.