# Mute Macbook pro when computer is shutting down

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite

I'm thinking of using the Mac's applescript to make a program that mutes the system when it is shutting down.

Though I'm new to applescript and I don't know how to use the IF-statement to determine if the system is shutting down. I've done some googling and I've found that the finder app is the app that is "controlling" the shutdown, but i don't know how to check if the state is "shut down". Can anybody assist me in this matter?

Comment: I've added an AppleScript solution with instructions to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- **AppleScript has no direct mechanism for detecting a shutdown/logout**.
- It does have a **mechanism for creating applications** that **can react to  *themselves* being *quit***.
- Thus, you can:

  - use **AppleScript to create a stay-open application** (`.app` bundle) with a **standard `on quit` handler**, in which you perform the desired action (
  - **make sure that the application is launched on login** - in the simpler case as a **Login Item** (via `System Preferences`, see below), or, with more flexibility but complexity, as a **launch agent** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872222/45375).

---

**Instructions:**

- Open `Script Editor` and open a new script window.
- Paste the following code:

```applescript
# This standard handler is called when the application quits.
on quit
    # Mute the system volume.
    # !! See caveat below.
    set volume with output muted
    continue quit  # signal to the system that it's OK to quit
end quit
```

- Save the script as a *stay-open application*:

  - with `File Format` **Application**
  - **check** `Stay open after run handler`
- Open `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items`, drag the newly saved `*.app` bundle into the list, and check the checkbox next to it, so as to make it launch hidden.

The final step is to hide the new application's Dock icon, as there's no reason for it to have one:

- From Terminal, run the following:

```sh
 defaults write /full/path/to/newApp.app/Contents/Info.plist LSUIElement 1
```

<sup>Note: You could use `LSBackgroundOnly` too, but the advantage of `LSUIElement` is that you can still display UI elements if you *want* to, such as for debugging.</sup>

**Important**: Substitute the full path of your new app for `/full/path/to/newApp.app`; the command **will only work** if you specify the ***full* path** to the `Info.plist` file.

To test, start the new app interactively, and make sure that no Dock icon appears. (You can quit the app via `Activity Monitor`).

**CAVEAT**: If the intent is to **suppress the system startup sound**, `set volume with output muted` has two drawbacks:

- it will not work if headphones happened to be plugged at the time of shutdown
- you will have to *unmute* the volume on *startup* (however, you could do that in an on `on run` handler in the same app).

Consider the alternative approach below, which requires admin privileges to set up and invokes `nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80` with root privileges, which bypasses the above drawbacks.

You *could* run `do shell script "nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80" user name "someAdminUsername" password "matchingAdminPassword" with administrator privileges` from the above AppleScript app, but you'd have to hard-code the password, which is not advisable for security reasons.

---

**Alternative approach**, using a **system-wide logout hook via `com.apple.loginwindow`**.

There's a *deprecated* mechanism for running a script on *logout* that, however, still works as of OSX 10.10; given that there's no direct non-deprecated equivalent, it may continue to be supported.

Note that you do need **admin privileges**:

```sh
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook <yourScript>
```

`<yourScript>` must be an executable, such as a shell script; note that the executable is run in the context of the *root* user.

In case you're thinking of muting the *startup sound*, invoke the following shell command from that script:

```sh
nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80  # to try this interactively, prepend `sudo `
```

This will mute sounds until *after* a reboot, effectively muting the startup sound, without *keeping* the sound muted.

<sup>Note that the `nvram` command requires *root privileges*, which are by definition in effect in a script run via the `com.apple.loginwindow` logout hook.; by contrast, to try the command *interactively*, use `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80` - otherwise, you'll get the following, unhelpful error message: `nvram: Error setting variable - 'SystemAudioVolume': (iokit/common) general error`</sup>

Comment: The `nvram...` command gives `nvram: Error setting variable - 'SystemAudioVolume': (iokit/common) general error` on OSX Yosemite :-(

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The (unhelpful) error message indicates that you didn't run the command with `sudo`. I didn't include `sudo` in my answer, because a logout hook is run as root, but I'll update my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Oh, excellent! Thanks for working out that very unhelpful message!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it is better to make a deterministic solution. What I mean is, is that you make a script that:

- Mutes your computer.
- Shuts it down.

Then you take your script and create an Automator service, that you can assign to some shortcut, to make it easier for you to use it.  ctrl-opt-cmd-eject or something. :)

This is just how I would have solved it, if I have the need, it is short and sweet to make work, and should work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **LogoutHook** mentioned in @mklement0's  answer.

You can use the normal Applescript command `set volume with output muted`.

You just need to add the osascript shebang to the top of the Applescript document

i.e

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript


set volume with output muted
```

And then save the file as applescript text file.

In the save dialogue use :  ***file format: Text*** )

It will get the extension **.applescript**

Once it is saved, use Terminal.app to **chmod** the script as you would a normal shell script which in effect it is.

i.e

```
/bin/chmod +x foo.applescript
```

Then  add it to the loginwindows LogoutHook.

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook foo.applescript
```

Comment: That's helpful in general, but the limitations of using `set volume with output muted` still apply:
(a) it will not work if headphones happened to be plugged at the time of shutdown, and (b) you will have to _unmute_ the volume on _startup_.

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is an old post but for anyone still looking how to do this(like I was) I have a simple method.
Before I started Scripting I created a new folder in my home folder called toolbar scripts.(this is optional)
With the desktop showing Finder click on Go >Utilities >Script Editor.
In the window that opens type in or copy and paste the code

```
set volume with output muted
tell application "finder"
shut down
end tell
```

Click on the last button above the script you added - it should be compile. If you cannot find that button then on the top click on Script >Compile
Click on File >Save in the save as I called mine shutdown and chose the script folder (this is optional) 
Down the bottom of the dialog box at file format click on the arrow and change the format to application and click on save.

Open the folder you saved it in and drag the icon to the dock. Click on the icon you just put in the dock.
now if all is right this should mute the volume and shutdown the computer.
This will not shutdown the computer if you still have anything open.

Cheers
Peter

Answer (score 0):

first, you should create a sound-off script (with terminal)

```
sudo nano /Library/Scripts/sound-off.sh
```

after filling it with these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e ‘set volume output muted 1’
```

and make a sound-on script like that

```
sudo nano /Library/Scripts/sound-on.sh
```

and fill it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e ‘set volume 4’
```

then access them as executing files

```
sudo chmod u+x /Library/Scripts/sound-off.sh
sudo chmod u+x /Library/Scripts/sound-on.sh
```

and the last part is set them when the mac device is turn off and on:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook /Library/Scripts/sound-off.sh
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Library/Scripts/sound-on.sh
```