# How can I remap my OSX keyboard without using third-party programs?

Tags: macos, vim

I currently am using Seil to remap caps-lock to escape on OSX 10.11. Whenever I check htop just to see what is running when the system isn't doing much of anything (programs open but not doing much processing), Seil is always up there and fluctuating in its cpu and memory use. It probably isn't a big deal, but it feels crazy to have to always run this thing considering I only use vim for occasional flat text files. I don't want to have to start Seil every time I use vim. Is my best option to just disable caps lock and physically attach a bridge up to the escape key? Vim comes standard on OSX and is unusable without remapping escape to something, so I would think this would come up instead of relying on someone else to make an app for it.

Comment: Do you have xmodmap? I don't know if that works on OS X.

Comment: @yellowantphil Not unless it came with all the xcode stuff that you have to install for a bunch of *nix stuff to work. I haven't heard of it so I will have to read around. I just thought of maybe altering vim (plugin?) to use caps-lock (or something else) as escape. Better to wear shoes than clothe the world in leather and all that, but I am not sure if that would work yet.

Comment: and especially for vim you can also use `Ctrl-]` - or there are more ideas in this list: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remap Caps Lock to Control

You can remap the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key to the <kbd>control</kbd> key in the keyboard settings (click on the `Modifier Keys` button).

[image]

In vim, an alias for <kbd>esc</kbd> is <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>, which is much more accessible than reaching for the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

## Remap Caps Lock to Escape in Vim

Navigate to the `Library/Preferences/ByHost` directory under the home folder

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

Identify the hidden property list file

```
ls -a | grep Global
```

Assign it to a shell variable for easy referencing later

```
pfile=$(ls -a | grep Global)
```

Make sure the newly created variable `pfile` has the right value. It should look something like this: `.GlobalPreferences.7D7C488E-0E83-5562-B58B-011C540890F3.plist`

```
echo $pfile
```

Make a backup just in case something goes horribly wrong

```
cp $pfile{,.bak}
```

Copy the pfile to the home directory and convert it to xml

```
cp $pfile ~/keys-binary.plist
plutil -convert xml1 -o ~/keys-xml.plist ~/keys-binary.plist
```

Open the file and search for the text `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc` and `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst`. Set the value in between the `integer` tags under `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst` to 5 and under `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc` to 0, as follows.

```
 <key>com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-588-0</key>
 <array>
     <dict>
         <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
         <integer>5</integer>
         <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
         <integer>0</integer>
     </dict>
 </array>
```

Save, then convert back to a binary file

```
plutil -convert binary1 -o ~/keys-binary.plist ~/keys-xml.plist
```

Finally, copy this file back to the `ByHost` directory, replacing the original file.

You'll need to log out and back in before the changes take effect. Once you have logged back in, add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
noremap  <Esc>Op <Esc>
noremap! <Esc>Op <Esc>
```

This is going to work if you open vim in the terminal. If you are using gvim, try out [Solution 2 by eelco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x) which I referenced to write this post with a couple of different mappings to make it work in the terminal.

Note also that, for this to work, the *Allow VT100 application keypad mode* option in your Terminal Preferences must be checked.

Comment: This is a pretty good alternative for most people, but the metacarpals in my right hand pinky and ring finger have been broken and not healed properly. I try to limit their use and escape is easily the most used key in vim besides space. I should have searched harder initially and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308192/how-to-hook-remap-an-arbitrary-keyboard-event-on-osx?rq=1

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was wanting to do! I appreciate the work you put into this! Works perfectly!